# Prevent JLabel with html from breaking line

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel, jtree

Wondering if anyone knows how to disable line break when using html in JLabel.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class Main 
{
    private static final int[] TEXT = 
    {   0x05D0, 0x05B2, 0x05DC, 
        0x05B5, 0x05D9, 0x05DB, 
        0x05B6, 0x05DD 
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String text = "";
        for(int cp : TEXT)
            text += Character.toString(cp);
    
        String html = "<html>" + text + "</html>";
    
        JLabel label = new JLabel(html);
        JLabel msg = new JLabel("The text should at least go out to here.");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(msg);
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
    }
}
```

The bidi text breaks into two lines. I am trying to write html to a JTree node so it will support multiple font families.  I can't get it to work with a JLabel.  I'm thinking I might need to paint it in a cell renderer.  I was hoping to get the html to work.  It would make things a lot easier.

Any suggestions?

=== Edit ===
When my display setting in Windows is at 125% it breaks the line; however, when I change my display setting in Windows to 100% it does not break the line.  Running 1920 x 1080 display.  Anyone have any ideas? Or, is anyone able to repeat the breaking of the line?

=== Edit ===

Interestingly when I pass -Dsun.java2d.uiScale= with 1.0 or 2.0 it works.  When I use 3.0, 4.0, 1.25 or 1.5 or 0.8 it does not work.

Comment: I don’t see any line breaks when I run your program.  I see “אֲלֵיכֶם” on one line and “The text should at least go out to here.” on the second line.  By the way, your loop isn’t necessary;  you can just write `private static final String TEXT = "\u05D0\u05B2\u05DC\u05B5\u05D9\u05DB\u05B6\u05DD";`.

Comment: Sure enough, it works on Oracle JRE 8.  It does not work on OpenJDK.  I tried OpenJDK 11 and OpenJDK 15.  Seems to be a problem with OpenJDK.  Unfortunately,  I am sticking with OpenJDK due to Oracles new licensing arrangement.  Maybe someone using OpenJDK can take a look.  Also, I noticed Oracle JRE 8 does not support Character.toString(codepoint) - Did you need to change the code to make it work?

Comment: I used JPanel with grid layout to guarantee that the JLabel was full width

Comment: It does not work on my machine with OpenJDK 17 - here is an an image [Image linebreak](https://ibb.co/5xk3t3S)  Not sure why not.  Running Windows 10

Comment: Funny - When I change my Display setting from 125% to 100% in Windows it works

Comment: Does 125% work with OpenJDK 17?

Comment: No, 125% does not work with 11, 15, 16, 17 of OpenJDK.  Works at 125% with Oracle 1.8.0_131 (I know it is old, I just had a copy of it)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I submitted a bug report.  I managed to find a workaround that seems to work for all Windows Display Scale's but it is quite a hacky workaround.  But it will be sufficient until the bug is fixed.

Here it is:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;

public class Main 
{
    private static final String TEXT = 
    "\u05D0\u05B2\u05DC\u05B5\u05D9\u05DB\u05B6\u05DD";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB).getGraphics();
        FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
        String[] split = TEXT.split("");
        double width = 0;
        for(String chr : split)
            width += label.getFont().getStringBounds(chr, frc).getWidth();
            
        double scale = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution()/96.0;

        String html = "<html><p style=\"width:"+Math.ceil(width/scale)+"px;\">" + TEXT + "</p></html>";
    
        label.setText(html);
        JLabel msg = new JLabel("The text should at least go out to here.");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(msg);
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
    }
}
```

Note: If I don't get the individual character lengths then the width doesn't come out right in a JTree node.  Also, for some reason when I use bidi text the resultant width of the nodes JLabel is about twice the width of the text.  Any shorter and it does not display correctly.  However, the width is correct with Non-Bidirectional text.  Also, width: does not work with span tag, it only works with p tag

Comment: Turns out this bug has already been reported https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8269854